# How do I mark a file as deleted in a tree using the GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-api

Using the GitHub API, I can [create a tree](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#create-a-tree) containing all the modified files for a commit, specify a `base_tree` that will be updated with this tree of changes and then commit it.

But, as the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#create-a-tree) says, the new tree can contain only paths for files with the modes

> `100644` for file (blob), `100755` for executable (blob), `040000` for
>   subdirectory (tree), `160000` for submodule (commit), or `120000` for
>   a blob that specifies the path of a symlink.

It doesn't say what should I do if I want to mark some path as deleted, as with `git rm <path>`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@ivan-zuzak 's answer is obsolete now that the GitHub API supports deleting files by passing null sha's.

To delete a file you would create a tree in Javascript with octokit like so:

```js
await octokit.request('POST /repos/{owner}/{repo}/git/trees', {
  owner: 'octocat',
  repo: 'hello-world',
  tree: [
    {
      path: 'path/to/file-that-will-be-deleted.py',
      mode: '100644',
      type: 'blob',
      sha: null,
    }
  ],
  base_tree: 'sha'
})
```

The base_tree should contain the SHA1 of an existing Git tree object you want to delete the file from.

After that everything Ivan said still holds true, so you should construct a new commit that links to this new tree, and bump the ref to point to this new commit.

Comment: Trying to loop through all items in the tree and set `sha: null` to all those I need to remove. But Github API returns "Unprocessable Entity". If I remove these nulls from the tree - everything works but nothing happens actually, I think, because my new tree completely matches the old tree (though I removed unneded items instead of setting sha to null, it doesn't seem to work in terms of removing those items from the repo)

Comment: UPD: The reason of that error was marking folders with `sha: null`. But I tried with a single file. Didn't work, thought I didn't get any error. The file is still there

Comment: UPD2: I figured this out. I should specify base_tree which you actually mentioned :) worked well. thank you!

Comment: Bear in mind that the mode should be `100644` rather than `100664`

Comment: @AlfredoGallegos You are right, but Git did allow 100664 for rw-rw-r--, but that turned out to be a mistake. Git still supports 100664 since there may be some Git repositories that still have such entries, but unless you find a really old repository, you won't find any 100664s. source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139971/what-does-a-tree-mean-in-git

Comment: I've seen this answer multiple times, but whenever I use `sha: null`, I get a HTTP 422 error `GitRPC::BadObjectState`.

Edit: OK so deleting _folders_ this way is not supported? :o

Comment: @JHH *folders* isn't a concept that exists within git. There are only files (blobs) with filenames (paths). Paths can contain forward slashes so that we can think of the separate parts as folder names, but that is an illusion. To delete a "folder" you would have to delete all files contained in that "folder".

Answer (score 9):

Currently, the only way to remove an entry from the tree (either a blob or another tree) is to [construct a new tree](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#create-a-tree) and not list that entry. After you have that tree, [construct a new commit](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#create-a-commit) that links to this new tree, and don't forget to [bump the ref](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#update-a-reference) to point to this new commit.

Comment: If you run into any problems, feel free to let us know -- support@github.com.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can do that procedure you're talking about, then (tree-commit-ref).

Comment: Surprised that I'm the first upvoter here. Thanks for the response. This problem really should be addressed on the API page!

Comment: @IvanZuzak What if I'd like to only send the diff by providing a `base_tree` instead of sending the entire tree? Shouldn't there be a way to indicate that a file was deleted?

Comment: @MarcoJakob Not sure I understand. Mind sending an email to support@github.com and providing more details about your use case? Sharing as many details as possible helps us provide advice. Thanks

Comment: I have sent as well, but no response from you.

Comment: From what I gather we have to send the whole recursive tree otherwise nested directories will be removed. This seems quite unwieldy for simple needs (update/delete files in a directory). Would be a lot neater if we could just indicate the path should be deleted (e.g. pass null to sha)

Comment: @Dominic passing a null to sha is supported now. See my answer for the details.

Answer (score -2):

The most clean way to do this I've found is to [create a new branch](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#create-a-reference), **create**, **delete** and **update** files in it using the [contents API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/), then [create a merge commit with the master branch](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#create-a-commit) and finally [update the master branch to this last commit](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#update-a-reference) (in the end you should also [delete the temporary side-branch](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#delete-a-reference)).