# What does "a tree" mean in Git?

Tags: git

The manpage of `git diff` says it

> NAME
>
> git-diff - Show changes between commits, commit and working tree, etc
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> Show changes between **the working tree** and the index or **a tree**, changes between the index and **a tree**,
>   changes between **two trees**, changes between two **blob objects**, or changes between two files on disk.

Does "the working tree" mean the working directory?

What does "a tree" mean here?  Is it the same as a commit object or a tree object? (Literally, I think it means a tree object. But I guess it may intend to mean a commit object, by comparing the "DESCRIPTION" part to the "NAME" part.)

How do you specify "a tree" as a command line argument to `git diff`?

If I may also ask, how do you specify "a blob object" as a command line argument to `git diff`?

Answer (score 7):

The word *tree* is rather overloaded in Git (well, and, in computing in general).

The *work-tree* or *working tree* (or other variations of this spelling) refers to the place in which you do your work.  Here, files have their normal everyday form, and are readable and—OS willing—writable.  (On a Unix system, if you `chmod -w` your files, you won't be able to write them.  That's not Git's fault, though.)

A *tree object*, in Git, is an internal data structure that records a directory tree or sub-tree.  It contains one entry per file or sub-directory (or, for submodules, a *gitlink* entry for that submodule).  Each entry lists the file's executable-mode bit, as a sort of yes or no flag that's encoded weirdly,<sup>1</sup> plus the file's name and blob hash ID.  For a sub-tree, the entry lists the directory's name and the subtree object hash ID.  Git can then recursively work through the sub-tree object to find more files and yet more sub-trees as needed.  Each file entry gives a hash ID for a Git internal *blob* object, which is a frozen (read-only) compressed copy of the file's data.

Every commit saves one (1) internal Git tree object hash ID.  That tree object contains the snapshot that the commit contains—so a commit's snapshot is really one of these trees, which contains entries for files and subtrees.  Since each commit has exactly one tree, Git can convert from a commit-specifier to a tree object:

```
$ git rev-parse master
3c31a203fbeedb4d746889dc77cbafc395fc6e92
$ git rev-parse master^{tree}
5c4b695f5d5606976f5b72e1a901ed17db30a359
```

In this case, the *commit* identified by `master` is that first big ugly hash, but the internal *tree* object that this commit is using to hold the files is the second one.

Hence, a *work-tree* contains real files with real data, and a Git *tree object* allows Git to find all the frozen files of a commit, provided you give the tree object that corresponds to some commit.  The `git diff` command needs to compare two things.  Those two things can either be two individual files—this is sort of a degenerate case—or two *trees of files*.  When comparing two trees, whether they're tree objects or a work-tree full of files, `git diff` will:

- Compare the file *names* in each tree.
- If they match, Git assumes these are "the same file", and will compare the files' contents.
- If they *don't* have matching names, optionally, attempt to match up the files by content.
- If all else fails, tell you that some file(s) were deleted and some file(s) were added.  The contents of a deleted file are all deleted; the contents of an added file are all-new.

This is still just an overview, because `git diff` can do more than just these things, but those are the basics.

There's one more very important wrinkle: `git diff` can inspect the *index* and treat it as a tree.  The index holds copies of files taken from somewhere.  That *somewhere* is, initally, whatever commit you `git checkout`-ed.  However, you can `git add` files from the work-tree to copy them into the index, replacing the version that was there from the commit.  You can `git add` files from the work-tree that were never in the commit, and are thus new to the index.  And, you can `git rm` files, with or without `--cached`, to take files *out* of the index.

Since Git will build a *new* commit from whatever is in the index at the time you run `git commit`, comparing the index contents to something—a frozen tree from a commit, or the work-tree—is a very useful thing indeed.

---

<sup>1</sup>The actual tree entries store (mode, path, hash) triples.  The `mode` is a string: `100755` for an executable file, `100644` for a non-executable file, `40000` for a sub-tree, `120000` for symbolic link, and `160000` for a gitlink.  These were originally Linux's `stat` `st_mode` fields, and Git allowed `100664` for `rw-rw-r--` for instance, but that turned out to be a mistake, so a normal tree only uses one of the limited subset.  Git still supports `100664` since there may be some Git repositories that still have such entries, but unless you find a really old repository, you won't find any 100664s.  The hash is always a blob hash *except* for gitlink entries, where the hash is the desired commit hash in the submodule.

Answer (score 1):

The current working directory is wherever your shell thinks it is.  The current working tree starts in the directory with the .git repos.  If it says working directory, you might think it moves when you do - it doesn't.

As far as referencing a tree from the git repo, I don't see that terminology in the docs; the only tree I recall seeing is the working tree.

But to get the task you're asking about done, I usually use the signature from the log line of the particular commit.  If it's the current commit, then either saying 'HEAD' or the name of your branch works.  If it's the head of a different branch, naming that branch can work.  If it's tagged, the tag name works.  There's also HEAD^1 for the prior commit.