# git compare commits between 2 trees

Tags: git, github

I have 2 trees like this

```
tree-1                                                
   -->branch-A                                      
          commit-ABC                                  
          commit-DEF                                  
          commit-XYZ
```

```
tree-2
    -->branch-AA                                         
          commit-ABC                                   
          commit-DEF                                   
          commit-XYZ
```

Note: commit-ABC in branch-A and commit-ABC in branch-AA have same commit message and might have different code changes and hash value.

Tree here is my repo.

I need to filter out the commits between branch-A and branch-AA which have same code changes and not just based on hash of the commits. How can I do this?

Comment: https://devconnected.com/how-to-compare-two-git-branches/

Comment: What's a "tree"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139971/what-does-a-tree-mean-in-git

Answer (score 0):

`git cherry -v branch-A branch-AA` will give you a first view ;

`git log` also has options to that end : see [`--cherry-mark`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---cherry-mark), [`--cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---cherry-pick) and [`--cherry`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---cherry).

---

The `git log` options work with symmetric differences (e.g : 3 dots notation `branchA...branchB`)

The simplest one to use is `--cherry` :

```
# will list commits on branch-AA, and mark with '=' those that exist on branch-A :
git log --cherry branch-A...branch-AA

# to see the other side :
git log --cherry branch-AA...branch-A

# you can combine with other git log options :
git log --oneline --cherry ...
git log --graph --format=... --cherry ...
# etc ...
```

Here is a set of options I find convenient to have both branches in one single view :

```
git log --graph --oneline --boundary --cherry-mark branch-A...branch-AA
```

If you want to filter out commits, rather than displaying them with a `=` :

- replace `--cherry-mark` with `--cherry-pick` in that last command,
- add `--right-only` (resp `--left-only`) to view only the `branch-AA` part (resp the `branch-A` part).

Comment: I **think** branch-A and branch-AA are in different repos. Though what a "tree" is, is unclear

Comment: @Liam : ah, good point, in that case there would be an extra step to fetch one repo into the other

Comment: Tree is actually my repo where .git is present

Comment: Will this solution work if the commit-ABC in branch-A has different hash compared to commit-ABC in branch-AA and still the changes are same in both the commits. The challenge here is a commit can't be compared based on just hash it has to compare based on the contents of both the commits.

Comment: @SrihariUttanur : yes (test it and you will see)